# Maven-surefire plugin excluding parallel test

Tags: maven, testng, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-java

i am using maven-surefire, cucumber and testng to run a few cucumber test in parallel, I would like to execute a few test in parallel and a few in serial order. PS- i am not using testng.xml but using testrunner.java to run my test.

Regards

Comment: Please see the annotation **@NotThreadSafe** and the documentation https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html There is exactly this problem solved. It goes with JUnit 4 - not TestNG and JUnit5.

Answer (score 1):

You can set-up parallel in your `pom.xml`. Need add configuration with thread count and parallel (methods, class, etc.)

Example:

```
</plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>methods</parallel>
          <threadCount>10</threadCount>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

Comment: With this all my tests are running in parallel, I want to run a few serially also. Feature file does not support @notthreadsafe annotations so need a different way to avoid using a feature file in parallel mode.

Comment: my problem is i have not used Test tag, i have tags mentioned in my .feature file, not sure how to create a Test tag dependency in feature file

Comment: The linked issue only involves tags from feature files.

Comment: Aditya, i wrote that @NotThreadSafe works with JUnit 4. The Cucumber also works with JUnit4. Can you migrate your tests from TestNG to JUnit?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the annotation **@NotThreadSafe** and the documentation https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html
There is exactly this problem solved. It goes with JUnit 4 - not TestNG and JUnit5.

Comment: I believe u cannot put @NotThreadSafe to a .feature file.

Comment: You have to use it on the test class.